# On Banach space , is every linear bounded projection map an open map?

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $X$ be a  Banach space and $P \in \mathcal B(X)$ be a projection ( i.e. $P^2=P$ ) . Is it true that $P$ is an open map in the sense that for every open set $U$ in $X$ , $P(U)$ is open in $P(X)$ ?

Comment: You may wish to check the *open mapping theorem*.

Comment: @user251257: $P \in {\cal B}(X)$ usually means $P$ is continuous...

Comment: If $P$ is a continuous projection, then the range of $P$ is itself a Banach space. Thus, by the open mapping theorem, the map $P$ is open. There is no reason, that I am aware of, as to why a discontinuous projection is an open map.

Comment: @user251257: $P$ is surjective on the Banack space $P(X)$, hence it is an open map. What claim are you referring to?

Comment: @SamM ah open in the range. I haven't read it properly. Sorry.

Comment: Yes. This is crucial. Note that $P(U)$ cannot be open in $X$ unless $P$ is the identity map on $X$. This is because no proper subspace of a normed space can have non-empty interior (easy exercise).